# Direct query grayed out in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am using Power BI which has been using a cached version of a query I now want to run it with the live query. Also, how do I use this if I am using two independent views for my data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the data source from Import to DirectQuery.  You will need to setup a new source and configure it as DirectQuery from the start.

There is a work-around, outside of Power BI:
http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Solution-Changing-datasource-from-Import-to-Direct-Query-gt/m-p/246569#M109251

Comment: So how would i do that so I need to setup a new datasource how would I cope with two independend fews I need to be able to use two views for two different tables.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  You can have multiple data sources in the same document.  However, for my experience, once I realized I wanted DirectQuery, I rebuilt my entire document, creating all of the data sources as DirectQuery.  Actually there is a kludge to change your existing data source if re-building is onerous.  I'll edit my answer, adding the link.